# The Lie Bracket of a Poisson Algebroid

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, poisson-geometry

Given a Poisson manifold $(M,\pi)$, define a bracket on $\Omega^1(M)$ by
$$
[\alpha,\beta]=\mathcal{L}_{\pi^\sharp(\beta)}\alpha-\mathcal{L}_{\pi^\sharp(\alpha)}\beta-d\pi(\alpha,\beta)
$$
Anti-symmetry is clear. But we need the Leibniz rule $[\alpha,f\beta]=f[\alpha,\beta]+(\rho(\alpha)f)\beta$, where the anchor map is $\rho(\alpha)=\pi(\cdot,\alpha)$. This gives me some trouble. Each time I try to prove this, I get the following term: $$d\pi(\alpha,f\beta)=d(f\pi(\alpha,\beta))=\pi(\alpha,\beta)df+fd\pi(\alpha,\beta)$$
The $df$ term should not be there. But I do not see how to make it go away, given the Leibniz rule of the exterior derivative. Could someone tell me how this works?

Comment: Doesn't it cancel out with "product term" of $\mathcal{L}_{\pi^\sharp(f\beta)}\alpha=\mathcal{L}_{f\pi^\sharp(\beta)}\alpha=f\mathcal{L}_{\pi^\sharp(\beta)}\alpha+df\wedge \iota_{\pi^\sharp(\beta)}\alpha$ ?

Comment: That is correct. I thought the Lie derivative was $C^\infty(M)$-linear in that argument. But of course, when testing that on vector fields we can easily see it is not (in the present case I should have been more careful with Cartan's formula). That is mildly embarrassing. Thank you.